# provide google maps api key from config.json file

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-2

I have config.json file where i have procided all urls and keys. There is one parameter called "googleMapsApiKey" where i have my "map key". I want to provide this key to my module file so that i can use google maps but I am unable to provide it. Below is my code.

config.json

```
{
      "googleMapsApiKey": "MY KEY",
   }
```

MobileContentModule.ts

```
import { ConfigService } from '../../../HiP-CmsAngularApp/app/config.service';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
          apiKey: 'WANT TO PROVIDE THAT KEY HERE', ---> from config.json
          libraries: ['places']
        }),
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
```

There is one service called ConfigService where I am accessing my config.json file. I have imported this service in MobileContentModule.ts file.

Can anyone help me to get my google api key from config.json file? Purpose of this is, that we dont want to expose this key on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import it in your file like so :

```
import data from './config.json';
[...]
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: data.googleMapsApiKey
  libraries: ['places']
}),[...]
```

But `TypeScript 2+` will complain about `Cannot find module 'config.json'`.
Then you'll have to use a wildcard declaration like

```
declare module "json!*" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

(see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations)

Comment: I can not do this because when i push this code, it can not build because this config.json file in not present on our TFS. I already tried this way, still i will try this....is there any other to get that key after importing?

Comment: So the problem is not related to "how you import it", but "why you don't have that file available on your build server" ?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is related to TFS or not...after pushing my code, i have got below error. config.json file is not in our git repo where TFS is getting the code and that is why build fails...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../hip-config.json' in 'C:\agent_tfship\_work\1\s\app\mobile-content'

Comment: @ylerjen...i forgot to mentioned that it worked...i have declared wildcard component and read this key...Thanks for the valuable suggestion!

Comment: @ylerjen I followed this approach and it worked fine with ng serve but in deployment, the key isn't loaded and the map goes to dev env

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 6.1+:

app.module.ts

```js
import * as fromConfig from 'config.json';

@NgModule({
imports: [
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: fromConfig.googleJSAPIKey,
            libraries: ['places'],
        }),]
})
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```